# Magento Error "Order saving error: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1205 Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction" at backend

Tags: magento-1.9, sales-order

Magento showing error **Order saving error: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1205 Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction,**  on placing order at backend.
Still Order has been saved with status "pending" and then if I generate invoice, this does not show MRP in invoice PDF.

So I need to cancel this order and have to reorder this, this time there no error appears.

I am not aware about this what is happening there and its cause.

can anyone help to to resolve this problem

Answer (score 1):

This error means that the table is `locked` by another process. In MySQL database when a process is launched on table, it lock the table to avoid another process to messed up with the first one (like cron in Magento)
You can increase the variable `innodb_lock_wait_timeout` to avoid this error but take care this could be the result of an another process.
For example if you have a cron that make action on this table and run for a long time, this could lock the table and generate this error when another process try to access the table.
In short try to look if you have a process that make actions in your database in the same time and increase the `innodb_lock_wait_timeout` variable.

---

***Source / help***
 - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/innodb/1.1/en/innodb-other-changes-innodb_lock_wait_timeout.html
 - https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/101000